# Custom textField with no label animation in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm having an issue with creating a TextField in my application. I need the border thickness of the TextField to be changeable based on certain conditions. Additionally, I want to disable any label animation that typically occurs when TextField is focused or unfocused.

However, I want the label to remain fixed on the border of the TextField at all times, without it moving into the TextField when the focus changes. I've tried a few approaches, but I haven't been able to achieve this desired behavior yet.

Could someone please provide guidance or suggest a solution on how to implement a TextField with a changeable border thickness and without any label animation in the focused and unfocused states, while keeping the label fixed on the border? Thank you in advance for your assistance!

```
@Composable
fun CustomTextFieldBordered(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    readOnly: Boolean = false,
    value: String?,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    maxLength: Int = 50,
    isValid: ((String) -> Boolean)? = null,
    label: String? = null,
    keyboardType: KeyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
    imeAction: ImeAction = ImeAction.Done,
    maxLines: Int = 1,
    trailingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.extraLarge,
    labelColor: Color? = null,
    containerColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary.copy(0.1f),
    focusedBorderColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
    unfocusedBorderColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary.copy(0.75f),
    placeholder: String? = null
) {
    val focusRequester = FocusRequester()
    var focusState by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var color by remember {
        mutableStateOf(unfocusedBorderColor)
    }
    val animatedColor by animateColorAsState(targetValue = color, label = "")
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = focusState) {
        color = if (focusState)
            focusedBorderColor
        else
            unfocusedBorderColor
    }

    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        BasicTextField(
            modifier = modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                .onFocusChanged {
                    focusState = it.isFocused
                },
            readOnly = readOnly,
            value = value ?: "",
            onValueChange = { text ->
                if (text.length <= maxLength) {
                    onValueChange(text)
                }
            },
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            enabled = true,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = keyboardType, imeAction = imeAction),
            singleLine = maxLines == 1,
        ) {
            OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.DecorationBox(
                value = value ?: "",
                innerTextField = it,
                enabled = true,
                singleLine = maxLines == 1,
                visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                label = {
                    label?.let {
                        CustomText(
                            text = label,
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
                            color = animatedColor,
                            fontSize = 12.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                        )
                    }
                },
                placeholder = {
                    placeholder?.let {
                        CustomText(
                            text = placeholder,
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium.copy(color = Color.Gray),
                            color = Color.Gray
                        )
                    }
                },
                colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                    focusedContainerColor = containerColor,
                    unfocusedContainerColor = containerColor,
                    disabledContainerColor = containerColor,
                    focusedBorderColor = focusedBorderColor,
                    unfocusedBorderColor = unfocusedBorderColor,
                ),
                contentPadding = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.contentPadding(),
                container = {
                    OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.ContainerBox(
                        enabled = true,
                        isError = false,
                        interactionSource = interactionSource,
                        colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                            focusedContainerColor = containerColor,
                            unfocusedContainerColor = containerColor,
                            disabledContainerColor = containerColor,
                            focusedBorderColor = focusedBorderColor,
                            unfocusedBorderColor = unfocusedBorderColor,
                        ),
                        shape = shape,
                        focusedBorderThickness = 2.dp,
                        unfocusedBorderThickness = 2.dp,
                    )
                },
            )
        }
        trailingIcon?.let {
            trailingIcon()
        }
    }

}
```

Like this:
[image]

Comment: did you find a solution to this ?